# Form Fields in a tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip, modal-dialog

I want to display the form fields same as appearing on the below mentioned URL:---

https://quotes.tiger.co.uk/motorquoter/yourdetails.aspx

Means when the User clicks on any field a modal popup with that field should appear.

Can anybody please help me how to implement this one or which plugin should be best for this purpose.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Tried anything?? Or Googled any stuff? Please share it, it would be helpful for people to help & answer .

Comment: Yes I tried to google it but didn't get any meaningful plugins yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Plugin as such, will update my answer if i get any.

You can get this done by something like below(you may call it as crude way, but may be it helps you clicking some brilliant idea) :-

Refer your `jQuery` file in `HTML`.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
```

Create a `input` elements like

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" onclick="parent.focuswhere = 0;" id="firstName" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Now, keep you dialog ready in HTML.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" onclick="parent.focuswhere = 0;" id="Text1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

You are all set, with HTML. Now coming to jQuery code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input").click(function (e) {
            $("#dialog").dialog();
            console.log(e.target);
        });
    });

</script>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/uUgsF/)

Now, you can see I have `console.log(e.target);` at my `.click` function. You will get the clicked `<input>`. You can play around by creating dom element dynamically or in the same way as i have displayed above.

Not sure whether it will help you. But just see if you get some hint and bring out something cool..